# Add replicate column to end of matrix

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a matrix of one column and 6 rows. I would like to replicate that column *i* times but change one value randomly each time, and after each iteration, calculate the mean and variance across all columns.

For example:

```
values = rnorm(6, 6, 1); matrix1 = matrix(values, 6)
```

After i=1, would look like:

```
values2 = values
values2[sample(1:6, 1)] = values2[sample(1:6, 1)]+runif(1, 0, 1)
matrix2 = matrix(c(values, values2), 6)
```

At the end, I would like to output a data frame that looks like so:

```
i   mean   var
1   1.23  2.31
2   1.24  2.33 etc...
```

For many *i*'s.  I imagine there is a way to do this with loops, but my skills are not such that I can figure it out. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how many times you're doing this, it would be best to construct your final matrix beforehand, especially if i is large.  However, without that:

```
jitter.func <- function(x, vec) {
  cell <- sample(1:length(vec), 1)
  vec[cell] <- vec[cell] + runif(1, 0, 1)

  return(c(mean=mean(vec), var=var(vec)))
}


i <- 10
sapply(1:i, jitter.func, vec=values)
```

Comment: This works great. thank you, but perhaps I shot myself in the foot by simplifying my example. The function I am using in place of mean and var requires that the column names are different. I would like to label the colnames based on the iteration i.  I added this line in the function:  colnames(vec)=paste("col",1:length(vec),sep=""). But I get in error saying that the dimnames is not equal to array extend. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
j <- 20 # Number of columns 
i <- 6 # Number of rows
vec <- matrix(rnorm(i,6,1),ncol=j,nrow=i)# vector replicated j times
idx <- sample(seq(i),j,replace=TRUE) # j random rows
vec[cbind(idx, seq(j))] <- vec[cbind(idx, seq(j))]+runif(j) # add random number to random row in each column
apply(vec,2,plyr::each(mean,var)) # summary statistics
```